# Ignite's snapshot of nodes participating in load balancing is not updated when server node gets bounced for topology with 1 server node

Tags: ignite

Ignite's load balancers (e.g. RoundRobinGlobalLoadBalancer) don't handle server node bounce when there are N client nodes, but only 1 server node. The problem exists, because there is no other server node which will post/handle EVT_NODE_FAILED, EVT_NODE_JOINED, EVT_NODE_LEFT events for the only server node. Thus, if some client node is using remote proxy like it is shown in a code snippet below

`public <T> T locate(String serviceName, Class<T> serviceClass) {
        return ignite.services().serviceProxy(serviceName, serviceClass, false);
    }`

then after server node is bounced you will get a failure trying to use the proxy, i.e. IgniteException "Task topology does not have alive nodes".

To resolve this issue now for a mentioned topology (with 1 server node) i have to specify custom "loadBalancingSpi" in IgniteConfiguration which is using fixed version of RoundRobinGlobalLoadBalancer. In a fixed balancer's code I am also subscribing to EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED, which is being sent to client nodes. This way i ensure the snapshot of nodes is updated with UUID of a server node which is being bounced.

Does someone know if there is an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service proxy should not go through load balancer at all, because it manually maps to a particular node prior to closure execution. This is already fixed in master branch, and your scenario works there.

As for the node snapshot in load balancer, you're right that there is an issue. Here is the ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2975

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and thanks for raising a ticket. Btw, i think AdaptiveLoadBalancingSpi may have same issue with update of nodes snapshot.